# Keyboard, touchpad, WiFi not working Ubuntu 17

Tags: .desktop

I turned off my computer and I closed the lid before it completely shut down. The next morning I saw that it was still running since it did not completely shutdown, probably from closing the lid too soon.

Upon turning it on, I noticed the fan was revving high, it never revs high.

I tried to login in, but the keyboard and touchpad didn’t work. 
I have a wireless mouse attached and it still works.
Luckily, the universal access icon was available and I logged in by using the wireless mouse. Then I try get WiFi and it is not working at all. I’m not sure where to start.

Comment: I'd try to reboot.

Comment: Not sure if it helps anyone but it resolved itself after the battery completely drained and after 12 reboots.